# Cree en Python una matriz MXN con valores aleatorios, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que todos los bordes de esta sean 0?

Tags: python, matrices

He creado en Python la siguiente matriz

```
    from random import *

N = 7
M = 11

m = [[randint(1,10) for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

for f in m:
    print(f)

[2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 9, 1, 7, 7, 7, 4]
[4, 8, 1, 9, 9, 6, 6, 10, 9, 2, 7]
[7, 7, 8, 5, 1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10]
[7, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 9, 7, 8, 3]
[3, 9, 10, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 10, 8, 5]
[5, 4, 2, 2, 10, 9, 9, 9, 10, 3, 8]
[9, 8, 9, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8, 6, 6]
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo lograr que los bordes tengan valor 0, con los bordes me refiero a la primera y ultima fila y la primera y ultima columna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma seria iterar en la matriz y reemplazar toda su primera y última lista por ceros `0` y con el resto solo cambiamos su primer y último elemento

```py
import numpy as np

N = 7
M = 11

m = [[np.random.randint(1,10) for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

for f in range(len(m)):
    if f == 0 or f ==len(m)-1: #si es el primer o último elemento 
      m[f] = [ 0 for _ in range(len(m[f]))] #reemplazamos con 0 todo
    else:
      m[f][-1] =0 #reemplazamos el último 
      m[f][0] =0 #reem0lazamos el primero 
    print(m[f])
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto, gracias por la explicación

Comment: De nada ^_^ agregue un `else` para que el remplazo de ceros (inicio y fin) no curra siempre, solo cuando **no** es la primera ni última línea

Answer (score 1):

**Solución**

Este código crea la lista de números aleatorios con bordes en cero en una sola operación:

```
m = [[randint(1,10) * int(all([i, i < cols - 1, j, j < rows - 1])) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

**Análisis**

¿Cómo llegamos a esta expresión? Primero, creemos una comprensión de listas doble que inicialize la matriz completa con valores aleatorios:

```
m = [[randint(1,10) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

Esta expresión es lo mismo que escribir

```
for j in range(rows):
    for i in range(cols):
        m[j][i] = randint(1,10)
```

El borde está compuesto de aquellas celdas que **no** cumplen las siguientes condiciones:

- La fila es mayor que cero (`j`) y menor que la última (`j < rows - 1`).
- La columna es mayor que cero (`i`) y menor que la última (`i < cols - 1`).

En lugar de usar una serie de expresiones conectadas con `and`, usare la función intrínseca `all`, que retorna `True` si todos sus argumentos (un iterable) son `True`.

```
all([i, i < cols - 1, j, j < rows - 1])
```

Aplicando la función `int()` a este resulto obtengo un `1` cuando la celda está dentro de los bordes y `0` para las celdas en el borde.

Entonces multiplico el número aleatorio por ese valor y termino así de formar la matriz.

**Demo**

```
from random import randint

cols = 7
rows = 11

m = [[randint(1,10) * int(all([i, i < cols - 1, j, j < rows - 1])) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

for f in m:
    print(f)
```

produce

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 5, 9, 7, 3, 1, 0]
[0, 6, 5, 7, 10, 6, 0]
[0, 8, 1, 7, 4, 4, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 8, 2, 6, 0]
[0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0]
[0, 5, 6, 4, 9, 1, 0]
[0, 5, 5, 10, 6, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 9, 1, 9, 10, 0]
[0, 8, 7, 7, 2, 9, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```